# How to get this sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I know the answer to this sum is $$\sum_{k=0}^{i+1} \begin{pmatrix} i+1\\ k\end{pmatrix} = 2^{i+1} $$ because of pascals rule but how do I evaluate the sum to get this?

TO clarify I used binomial theorem and pascals rule to show

> $$\sum_{k=0}^{i+1} \begin{pmatrix} i+1\\ k\end{pmatrix} = \sum_{k=0}^{i+1} (\begin{pmatrix}
> i\\ k\end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix}i\\ k-1\end{pmatrix}) = \sum_{k=0}^{i+1} \begin{pmatrix}
> i\\ k\end{pmatrix} + \sum_{k=0}^{i+1} \begin{pmatrix}i\\ k-1\end{pmatrix}$$ and want to keep evaluating this way to get to $$2^{i+1}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, note that for Pascal's rule ${{i+1}\choose k} = {i \choose k} + {i \choose {k-1}}$ to always work, you need to follow the convention that $n \choose k$ equals $0$ when $k < 0$ and when $k > n$. I'll be following this convention.

Look at this sum that you have on the right: $\sum_{k=0}^{i+1} {i \choose k}$. The last summand (when $k = i+1$) is ${i \choose {i+1}}$. According to the convention, this is zero. So we may omit the last summand, and your sum equals to $\sum_{k=0}^i {i \choose k}$.

In the second sum $\sum_{k=0}^{i+1} {i \choose k-1}$ the same thing happens with the first summand. For $k=0$ we have ${i \choose 0-1} = 0$. Omitting the first summand, we get the sum $\sum_{k=1}^{i+1} {i \choose k-1}$. By a change of variable this is the same as $\sum_{k=0}^i {i \choose k}$.

So the whole thing becomes $2 \cdot \sum_{k=0}^i {i \choose k}$. This is the same as what we began with, but instead of $i+1$ we have $i$, and the whole thing is multiplied by $2$.

If you go on doing this, you'll get the chain of equalities
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{i+1} {i+1 \choose k} = 2 \cdot \sum_{k=0}^i {i \choose k} =
2 \cdot 2 \cdot \sum_{k=0}^{i-1} {i-1 \choose k} = \ldots =
2^{i+1} \cdot \sum_{k=0}^0 {0 \choose k} = 2^{i+1}.
$$

Of course, to formalize this last step properly (the $\ldots$ in the middle), you would have to use induction.

Comment: Can you just clarify what you mean by  "By a change of variable this is the same as $\sum_{k=0}^i {i \choose k}$."

Comment: Of course. To avoid confusion, I'll make two consecutive changes instead of doing everything in once. We start with $\sum_{k=1}^{i+1} {i \choose k-1}$. Introduce a new variable $l = k-1$. When $k=1$, $l=0$. When $k=i+1$, $l=i$. As $k$ runs from $1$ to $i+1$, $l$ runs from $0$ to $i$. So, our sum becomes $\sum_{l=0}^i {i \choose l}$.

Comment: And for the second change of variable we can forget about the original expression with $k$, and look at the new expression $\sum_{l=0}^i {i \choose l}$. In this expression we can just replace $l$ by $k$ everywhere, and we get $\sum_{k=0}^i {i \choose k}$. You can think of it like this: we introduce a *new* variable $k$. We don't care about the *old* $k$ that we had in the beginning.

Comment: This may look like cheating, but it's not. For instance, look at these sums: $x = \sum_{k=0}^3 (k + 3)$, and $y = \sum_{k=1}^4 (k+2)$. You can get one from another by a change of variable. But if formalities aren't convincing, you can just manually expand the sums in this particular examples. You will get the same sum $3 + 4 + 5 + 6$ both times.

Comment: Thanks, really helped! How did you grasp this stuff? I'm used to getting 90% in every class but I find our Prof. doesn't teach us everything, and I'm only getting a 70% in discrete math

Comment: Also, if you're not entirely comfortable with $\sum$-notation and playing around with index variables, it can be helpful to also write these sums without $\sum$, using ellipsis. With $\sum_{k=1}^{i+1} {i \choose k-1}$ this gives you ${i \choose 0} + {i \choose 1} + \ldots + {i \choose i}$. Then you do the same with $\sum_{k=0}^i {i \choose k}$, and you get exactly the same thing.

Comment: I don't know. With stuff like this, it is useful not to try to just magically write the whole solution in general terms on the first try. Try to play with it. In this particular case you could start by looking at a small $i$, say $i=2$, and writing down the sum explicitly: ${3 \choose 0} + {3 \choose 1} + {3 \choose 2} + {3 \choose 3}$. Then you apply Pascal's rule to each term and see what happens. If you do this, you immediately see that weird stuff like ${2 \choose -1}$ pops up. That should bother you, and you should get down to it right as you see it.

Comment: At this point (in the "learning ladder") I guess it is important to "keep things real", look at specific examples and not only generic formulas. And also it is important to be thorough, to be bothered by each and every inconsistency that you see. Math is about precision, not necessarily in numbers (I don't recall $\pi$ to the 100th digit), but in logic. You cannot leave steps that you don't like behind.

Comment: Also, if you think that something the teacher does doesn't make sense, you should call him on that. If you are shy of your classmates, you can ask the teacher after class. I like that kind of thing when I teach, even if I really made a mistake. If people are asking, it means that at least they are listening.

Answer (score 1):

Define $f(i) = \sum_{k=0}^{i+1} {{i+1} \choose k}$. You can use induction to prove the formula $f(i) = 2^{i+1}$ for all $i$. Note the formula is true for $i = 0$. Then for $i \geq 0$, your Pascal expansion shows that the answer $f(i+1)$ satisfies $f(i+1) = f(i) + f(i)$ because the two summations on the right hand side of your Pascal expansion formula are equal to $\sum_{k=0}^{i+1} {{i+1} \choose k} = f(i)$, so you get $f(i+1) = 2*f(i) = 2*2^{i+1} = 2^{i+2}$ so the formula is proved for all $i \geq 0$ by induction.

Answer (score 0):

You use the Newton formula for $\left(a+b\right)^{n}$

$2^{i+1}=\left(1+1\right)^{i+1}=\sum_{k=0}^{i+1}\binom{i+1}{k}1^{k}1^{i+1-k}=\sum_{k=0}^{i+1}\binom{i+1}{k}$

Comment: clarified above a bit more on what I'm trying to do

Answer (score 0):

Use the binomial expansion formula:-

$$(x+y)^{i+1}={i+1 \choose 0}x^{i+1}y^0+{i+1 \choose 1}x^{i}y^1+{i+1 \choose 2}x^{i-1}y^2+\cdots+{i+1 \choose i+1}x^0y^{i+1}\\=\sum_{k=0}^{i+1}{i+1 \choose k}x^{i+1-k}y^k$$

where

$${a \choose b}=\frac{a!}{b!(a-b)!}$$

To evaluate $2^{i+1}$ simply set $x=y=1$, so you have

$$(1+1)^{i+1}=\sum_{k=0}^{i+1}{i+1 \choose k}$$

In order to show that $2^{i+1}$ is indeed the sum, I think induction is the best approach.

For $i=0$, we have ${1 \choose 0}+{1 \choose 1}=2=2^{0+1}$. Assume that
$$\sum_{k=0}^{m+1}{m+1 \choose k}=2^{m+1}$$

We need to show that
$$\sum_{k=0}^{m+2}{m+2 \choose k}=2^{m+2}$$

Using the expression for Pascal's formula, we have

$$\sum_{k=0}^{m+2}{m+2 \choose k}=1+\sum_{k=1}^{m+1}\left\{{m+1 \choose k}+{m+1 \choose k-1}\right\}+1$$

Now the second term is

$$\sum_{k=1}^{m+1}\left\{{m+1 \choose k}+{m+1 \choose k-1}\right\}\\=\left(\sum_{k=0}^{m+1}{m+1 \choose k}-1\right)+\left(\sum_{v=0}^{m+1}{m+1 \choose v}-1\right)=2^{m+1}+2^{m+1}-2$$

where we use the change of variable $v=k-1$, and the summations do equal $2^{m+1}$, as we hold this true by assumption.

Thus we have

$$\sum_{k=0}^{m+2}{m+2 \choose k}=1+2^{m+1}+2^{m+1}-2+1=2\cdot2^{m+1}=2^{m+2}$$

Comment: clarified above a bit more on what I'm trying to do

Answer (score 0):

If you want a combinatorial approach to evaluate your sum, note that ${i+1} \choose k$ is the number of ways to choose a subset of size $k$ from a set of $i+1$ objects. If you sum from $k=0$ to $k=i+1$ then you get the number of ways to get a subset of any size from a set of size $i+1$. This is equal to $2^{i+1}$, because for each element in the set you have two choices, whether to include the element in the subset or not.